# How to modify query string parameter before making downstream in Spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

How do I modify the query string in Spring Cloud Gateway before downstream to another service.

e.g.

```
gateway/api/foo?query=one|two|three&param=1

//to

service/api/foo?query=one%20two%20three&param=1
```

Is it possible in `application.yml` config file?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to achieve this. I didn't get a clean solution. I managed this with URL rewrite, as given below. Hope it helps.

URI uri = URI.create(route.getUri() + exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath()+ "?"+ encodedString);

ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(uri).build();

exchange.getAttributes().put(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, request.getURI());

return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());